# How to resolve multiple queries together using Sequelizejs

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, sequelize.js

I have this basic nodejs script:

```
var express = require('express'),
  Sequelize = require('sequelize'),
  promise = require('bluebird'),
  app = express(),
  optimus = new Sequelize('optimus', 'root', 'test', {host: '127.0.0.1', dialect: 'mysql'}),
  query = 'SELECT id FROM borrowers LIMIT 0,10',
  query2 = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM borrowers';

app.get('/', function(req,res) {

  var chain = new Sequelize.Utils.QueryChainer();

  console.log('begin');

  chain.add(optimus, 'query', [query,null,null,[]])
    .add(optimus, 'query', [query2,null,null,[]])
    .run()
    .success(function() {
      console.log('done');
    }).error(function(err) {
      console.log('oh no');
    });

  console.log('end');
  res.send('Hi Ma!');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
  }
);
```

Neither 'done' nor 'oh no' ever fires which leads me to believe that I can' chain raw queries in this manner.

What I'd really like to accomplish is to asynchronously resolve both queries and pass the results back via res.send().

I have to admit to being a complete n00b at nodejs so any insights into how to correctly structure this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The major issue with your code is the fact, that you are sending a response to the client/browser too early. Instead of `res.send`-ing at the end of the `app.get` method, you need to send the answer inside the success respectively inside the error callback. Here you are:

```
var express = require('express'),
  Sequelize = require('sequelize'),
  promise = require('bluebird'),
  app = express(),
  optimus = new Sequelize('sequelize_test', 'root', null, {host: '127.0.0.1', dialect: 'mysql'}),
  query = 'SELECT id FROM borrowers LIMIT 0,10',
  query2 = 'SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM borrowers';

app.get('/', function(req,res) {

  var chain = new Sequelize.Utils.QueryChainer();

  console.log('begin');

  chain
    .add(optimus.query(query, null, { raw: true }))
    .add(optimus.query(query2, null, { raw: true, plain: true }))
    .run()
    .success(function(results) {
      res.send({
        resultOfQuery1: results[0],
        resultOfQuery2: results[1]
      });
    }).error(function(err) {
      console.log('oh no', err);
    });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Listening on port %d', server.address().port);
  }
);
```

Please notice, that I changed the credentials to my local ones. Furthermore also check the arguments of `chain.add`. Instead of passing the values for an upcoming serial executation, we just throw the actual asynchronous methods into it and let the querychainer handle their promises.

Comment: So you ran this locally and it worked for you as described? In my example I could not get it to run console.log('done'); at all.